# What is wrong with my `if` statement?

Tags: php, syntax, if-statement

I'm using an if statement to declare whether a user is an admin, mod or neither with this code below, but its messing up by always making $status = "admin" even if that person is neither, this has really baffled me.

```
if($info['rights'] == "m") {
    $status = '<font color="#FFFFFF">(mod)</font>';
}elseif ($info['rights'] == "a"); {
    $status = '<font color="#FFFFFF">(admin)</font>';
}
```

Comment: dude you can't edit your question to remove the error once it's been pointed out to you. It makes the accepted answer nonsense now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You seem to have accidentaly added a semicolon (;) after the elseif, so the second code block is always getting executed.

Comment: Yeah, get rid of the semicolon on line 3 and everything should work as planned.

Answer (score 4):

Is there supposed to be a semi-colon after "a")?

Comment: @Ryan : you should, i spent a month trying to figure out what i had done wrong in a code. in one file i had $bla and in the other $b1a

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your code.

You can try this:

```
if($info['rights'] == "m") {
  $status = '<font color="#FFFFFF">(mod)</font>';
} else if ($info['rights'] == "a") {
  $status = '<font color="#FFFFFF">(admin)</font>';
}
```

Comment: protip: Spell the word "you" out using all three letters.

Comment: why i have to use 'You' if save my ms times with just 'U' ?

Comment: Because saying u instead of you makes you sound like a 13 yr old girl chatting to her friends on AIM.

Comment: That's not a reason enough. U is understandable, may be not as much as yr for year. Quite ok to be on internet forums. I have seen iow, ymmv, tl;dr, imo, ftw, fyi constantly here on SO, even from reputed users

Answer (score 1):

Is $info declared? Where is $info defined and assigned?